line spacing is slightly varying before a tblr
I have two questions here.
First, why does the space between the baseline of the line with \rule {...} {1ex} (kind of custom section) and the top of the tblr is changing when the line contains letters like p q y?
Second, I would like that the space before the itemize environment and the space before the tblr ( or bare text ) are equal. Same for the space at the bottom of itemize env. and at the tblr.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray,fontsize,fix-cm}

  \usepackage{fontspec,enumitem}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
  \setmainfont{CMU Bright}
  \setsansfont{CMU Bright}

\newlength\colonneun
\setlength\colonneun{2cm}
\newlength\sectiondebut
\setlength\sectiondebut{1ex}
\newlength\sectionfin
\setlength\sectionfin{2.6ex}

\changefontsize[14]{12.4}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\rule{\colonneun}{1ex} test with a list\par
\vspace{\sectiondebut}

\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt]
  \item SSSSSS 
  \item two
  \item three
\end{itemize}
\vspace{\sectionfin}

\rule{\colonneun}{1ex} with letters pqy\par
\vspace{\sectiondebut}

\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt]
  \item SSSMMMM
  \item two one
  \item two two
\end{itemize}
\vspace{\sectionfin}

\rule{\colonneun}{1ex} a tblr \par
\vspace{\sectiondebut}
2022 \hspace{1cm} SSSSSSSSSS 

\vspace{\sectionfin}

\rule{\colonneun}{1ex} section name with letters pqy \par
\vspace{\sectiondebut}
2022 \hspace{1cm} SSSSSSSSSS

\vspace{\sectionfin}

\rule{\colonneun}{1ex} before a tblr \par
\vspace{\sectiondebut}
\begin{tblr}{width=\textwidth,colspec={X[r,\colonneun]X[l]},colsep=3pt}
2022 & SSSSSSSSSS \\
\end{tblr}
\vspace{\sectionfin}

\rule{\colonneun}{1ex} \dots{} letters pqy \par
\vspace{\sectiondebut}
\begin{tblr}{width=\textwidth,colspec={X[r,\colonneun]X[l]},colsep=3pt}
2022 & SSSSSSSSSS \\
\end{tblr}
\vspace{\sectionfin}

\end{document}

